# Scrollview for Video and Text layout in Android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have made one layout where I have declared video on top and followed by text below it. Now I can make the text scroll but video stays still on top. I want the video + text to be scrollable.

To achieve this, I have done it somehow but I am not convinced that it is a good approach. I have created two XML files, in one I have put the video on top and text below it. And in second, I have called this layout and made it list view with scroll. Let me know a clean method to achieve scroll for video and text both.

Comment: Please post your code to see what have you done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >   
         <VideoView
              android:id="@+id/video_view"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          </VideoView>
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:text="@string/your_text" >
          </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```